# Entropy analysis using rolling window

Tags: r, time-series, entropy, rolling-computation

I want to calculate the entropy values for the multiple time series with the rolling window size of 500. I used roll-apply function with my code, but it is not working.

Please help me to calculate entropy (i.e. with the below code) in the rolling window size of 500.

For your convenience, here I am providing my entropy code so that it can be easier for you to suggest the application of rolling window size of 500 in the entropy method.

```
N<-nrow(ts)
r<-matrix(0, nrow = N, ncol = 1)
for (i in 1:N){
    r[i]<-approx_entropy(ts[,i], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(ts[,i]), elag = 1)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify version: 
code:

```
library('zoo')
ts <- matrix(rnorm(100000),1000,100)
library('zoo')
ts <- matrix(rnorm(100000),1000,100)
roll <- function(x){
  entropy <- function(x){
    output <- any function or code you like to put hear
    return(output)
  }
  r <- rollapply(x,width=500,by=1,FUN=entropy)
  return(r)
}
res <- apply(ts ,2,roll)
```

Old version:
the avobe code should work, it is an example of how can you do it:

```
library('zoo')
ts <- rnorm(10000)
entropy <- function(x){
   return(approx_entropy(x,edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(x), elag = 1))
}
r <- rollapply(ts,width=500,by=1,FUN=entropy)
```

Realize that as you are computing a rolling window function the output will have size equal to length(ts)-window_length+1.
If this don't work, with your data, please post an example of your data in order to see which is the problem. Also your function approx_entropy, because the problem/error may be there. If you probe the code with a simple functions as mean it work.
Hope it help !

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. But, I need to calculate rolling window for multiple columns. So, I applied for loop in the previous code. Hence, how to calculate separate rolling entropy for multiple columns of a sheet?

Comment: When I use the mean function you can use what ever function you have previously create.

Comment: Then for loop in the rolling entropy nfunction will be as per the following code, right?for (i in 1:N){
    r[i]<-approx_entropy(ts[,i], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd(ts[,i]), elag = 1)
}

Comment: loop in the rolling entropy function will be like this, right?                                                                                                    
       for (i in 1:N) {                                                                                 
   entropy[i] <- function (ts[,i]){
      return(approx_entropy(ts[,i], edim = 2, r = 0.2*sd (ts[,i]), elag = 1))                                                                                                     
}}

Comment: Please suggest the loop command in the rolling entropy code. Is my previous way in the last comment correct to proceed for the loop in the rolling entropy? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really know how you program your function, but were now say: "output <- any function or code .... "; there you have to put your entropy function, considering that it will be apply to a vector given as a result one value. Then the rest of the code will do the rolling window for each column for you.

Comment: Thank you So much, Santigo for your help. The code worked. Thank you very much for your well-explanation about the code.

Comment: Hii,                                                                                                                      Further, I want to plot the rolling results that stored in the R object. In fact, I became able to do that. But, problem is that I want the date column in my X-axis. When, I am plotting, I am getting the no. of observation (i.e. 1000, 2000, 3000,---------) in the X-axis. How to define daily date series and get that date column (at least the name of the year) in X-axis? Please suggest me.  Thanks.